# highcharts with the huge data unable show the graph which is the scatter type

Tags: highcharts

When I try to bind huge data to high chart which is a scatter type. Please tell me the way to fix it. When I tried to bind less data to it, it is working perfectly.

here is the code i have written.

```
var _energyType;
  var _options = {

    chart: {
        renderTo: _container,
        Type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        marginBottom: 100,
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor: null
    },
    title: { text: '' },

    xAxis: [{
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: p_AttributeName + ' (' + p_metricUOM + ')',
            margin: 15,
            tickInterval: 1
        }

    }],
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            turboThreshold: 10000000,
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: Summit.DV.Resources.Widget.Intensity + ' ( ' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_AttributeName + ' (' + p_metricUOM + ') ' + ')',
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            }
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        formatter: function () {
            var _strToolTip;
            _energyType = Summit.DV.Resources.Widget.Intensity + ' (' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_metricUOM + ')';
            _strToolTip = Summit.DV.Resources.Generic.Site + ' : ' + this.point.name + '<br/>';
            _strToolTip = _strToolTip + _energyType + ' : ' + Summit.DV.Common.FormatNumber(this.y, p_locale, 3, false) + '<br/>';
            _strToolTip = _strToolTip + p_energytype + ' (' + p_uomtype + ') : ' + this.point.value + '<br/>';
            _strToolTip = _strToolTip + p_AttributeName + ' (' + p_metricUOM + ') : ' + Summit.DV.Common.FormatNumber(this.x, p_locale, 0, false) + '<br/>';
            if (p_target != '') {
                _strToolTip = _strToolTip + Summit.DV.Resources.Widget.Target + ' (' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_metricUOM + ') : ' + Summit.DV.Common.FormatNumber(parseFloat(p_target), p_locale, 3, false) + '<br/>';
                _strToolTip = _strToolTip + 'Δ to Target (' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_metricUOM + ') : ' + Summit.DV.Common.FormatNumber(parseFloat(this.y) - parseFloat(p_target), p_locale, 3, false);

            }
            else {
                _strToolTip = _strToolTip + Summit.DV.Resources.Widget.Target + ' (' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_metricUOM + ') : ' + ' ' + '<br/>';
                _strToolTip = _strToolTip + 'Δ to Target (' + p_uomtype + '/' + p_metricUOM + ') : ' + ' ';

            }
            return (_strToolTip);

        }
    },
    labels: {
        items: [{
            style: {
                left: '40px',
                top: '0px',
                color: '#666666',
                font: 'bold 12px Calibri', color: 'Black',
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 0,
        margin: 10,
        itemWidth: 180,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return this.name.substring(0, 30);
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: usage
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bug in Highcharts, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3453).

Workaround is to enable markers directly in options:

```
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 30.0
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hn5ntm8q/5/